# CSS property inerithance of pages loaded with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

### My code

*style.css*

```
input.button, input.submit, button, .button{
color:blue;
}
```

*index.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#princ").html('Loading...');
$("#princ").load('page.php', function (responseText, textStatus, req) {
   if (textStatus == "error") {
      $("#princ").html('An error occurred!');
   }
});
</script>
<div id="princ"></div>
```

*page.php*

```
<input type="text"><input type="button" value="Send">
```

### What my code should do

Coloring the button of blue if loaded from index.php.

### What's not working

The CSS property is not applied.

### What I tried to do

I tried to modify the css code several times, and I discovered that this code:

```
input{
color:blue;
}
```

Shows the two `<input>` of page.php colored of blue: that means that the properties set in the CSS file are received by page.php

### My question

Should I expect this behavior? How can I reach my aim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem there is that your CSS is not specifying the button on your page. You currently have

```
input.button, input.submit, button, .button { color: blue; }
```

This will colour `input`s that have a class of "button" or a class of `submit` or any `button` element or any element with a class of "button". However, your `input` in `page.php` has no class, so is not caught by this CSS rule.

You could change `page.php` to the following, which adds the class "button" to your input button.

```
<input type="text"><input type="button" value="Send" class="button">
```

You have an alternative though, you could change your CSS rule to catch `input`s that have the type of "submit" like so:

```
input.button, input.submit, button, .button, input[type=submit] { color: blue; }
```

And your button should appear blue too.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: In addition to what @philnash said, inputs typed button or reset can also be set as the submit example: `input[type=button], input[type=reset] {}`.

Comment: Thanks @DavidMillar for your addition, I will keep that on mind :)

Comment: No problem. @Angelo - for the sake of code cleanliness and maintainability, it's always good to use type submit for submission buttons, type reset for reset buttons, and type button for all other actions. :)

Comment: @DavidMillar So should I use type="submit" even for forms that are sent via jquery and put return:false; to prevent the classic reload of the page?

Comment: Semantically, yes. `return false;` is one way to prevent normal handling, but I think the proper way is to catch the event in your function and do `event.preventDefault()`:

`myFunction = function (e) { e.preventDefault(); /* rest of the code*/ };`

Comment: Ok, thanks for your advises, I'm going to follow them :)